# Finite rank operators spanned by rank-one projections proof.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, projection

Consider the following proof from Murphy's '$C^*$-algebras and operator theory'

[image]

Could someone explain the equality $pu = u^{1/2} p u^{1/2}$. I can see that this holds when $u$ is invertible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $u=pu$. Since $u$ is selfadjoint, taking adjoints you get $u=up$. So $pu=up$. Then $pu^n=u^np$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and thus $pf(u)=f(u)p$ for all polynomials $f$. Since $u^{1/2}$ is a limit of polynomials on $u$ (it's actually a polynomial and not limit because $u$ is finite-rank, but we don't need that here), $pu^{1/2}=u^{1/2}p$.

Comment: Can you give a reference for $u^{1/2}$ is actually a polynomial? Maybe that will still be proven in Murphy's book?

Comment: It's an elementary consequence of the Spectral Theorem: since $u$ is selfadjoint and finite-rank, $$u=\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_jP_j$$ with $P_1,\ldots,P_m$ pairwise orthogonal. Now let $f$ be a polynomial with $f(\lambda_j)=\lambda_j^{1/2}$.

Comment: Ah I see. I must still read the section about spectral theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $u^{1/2}(H)=u(H)$ so $p$ is identity on the image of $u^{1/2}$ and $u^{1/2}pu^{1/2}=u^{1/2}u^{1/2}=u$.

Comment: Why is $u^{1/2}(H) = u(H)$?

Comment: Because $u$ is invertible on $u(H)$, and you know what to do with $\ker u=u(H)^\perp$.

Comment: Thanks, I see that $u: u(H)  \to u(H)$ is indeed invertible, but I still don't quite see how that helps :/

Comment: $H=u(H)\oplus\ker u$.  If you start with anything element $h$ of $u(H)$ you know $pu(h)=u^{1/2}pu^{1/2}(h)$.  If you start with anything in $\ker u$ then both give 0.  So they agree on the pieces and so the whole of $H$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't understand this answer. Would you mind adding more details? I will award a bounty once I can if I understand it.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because I could understand it immediately but the offer still stands!